# Simplifying numerical expressions involving special functions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions

I've encountered the following problem. There is the identity ([Legendre's relation](http://dlmf.nist.gov/19.7.E1)) that the special functions `EllipticK[x]` and `EllipticE[x]` satisfy:

$$K(x)E(1-x)+E(x)K(1-x)-K(x)K(1-x)=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

*Mathematica* does not seem to know it so I included it into assumptions:

```
$Assumptions = EllipticK[x] EllipticE[1 - x] + EllipticE[x] EllipticK[1 - x] -
               EllipticK[x] EllipticK[1 - x] == Pi/2
```

If I now evaluate

```
Simplify[EllipticK[x] EllipticE[1 - x] + EllipticE[x] EllipticK[1 - x] - 
       EllipticK[x] EllipticK[1 - x]]
```

I will get `Pi/2`, fine. The problem is that I want this identity to be used not only symbolically but also numerically, i.e. for example I would like *Mathematica* to simplify

```
Simplify[EllipticE[2/3] EllipticK[1/
   3] + (EllipticE[1/3] - EllipticK[1/3]) EllipticK[2/3]]
```

down to `Pi/2`. Not only It does not happen when I just stated this identity symbolically but even direct evaluation with this assumption does not yield desirable answer. Namely,

```
FullSimplify[
 EllipticE[2/3] EllipticK[1/
    3] + (EllipticE[1/3] - EllipticK[1/3]) EllipticK[2/3], 
 Assumptions -> 
  EllipticE[2/3] EllipticK[1/
      3] + (EllipticE[1/3] - EllipticK[1/3]) EllipticK[2/3] == Pi/2]
```

returns

```
EllipticE[2/3] EllipticK[1/
   3] + (EllipticE[1/3] - EllipticK[1/3]) EllipticK[2/3]
```

How can I get `Pi/2` there instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following transformation function works in this case:

```
xfn[e_] := e /. EllipticK[x_] EllipticE[y_] /; x + y == 1 :> 
    Pi/2 - (EllipticE[x] EllipticK[y] - EllipticK[x] EllipticK[y]);

FullSimplify[
 EllipticE[2/3] EllipticK[1/3] + (EllipticE[1/3] - EllipticK[1/3]) EllipticK[2/3], 
 TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, xfn}]

(* π/2 *)
```

---

Edit:

The reason the using `$Assumptions` does not work as it is used in the question is that the assumption is effectively about the symbol `x`.  It will not be used as a general identity about elliptic integrals.

For instance, having the assumption in terms of `x` and the expression in terms of `y` results in no simplification:

```
Block[{$Assumptions = 
   EllipticK[x] EllipticE[1 - x] + EllipticE[x] EllipticK[1 - x] - 
     EllipticK[x] EllipticK[1 - x] == Pi/2}, 
 Simplify[EllipticK[y] EllipticE[1 - y] + 
   EllipticE[y] EllipticK[1 - y] - EllipticK[y] EllipticK[1 - y]]
 ]

(* EllipticE[y] EllipticK[1 - y] + (EllipticE[1 - y] - EllipticK[1 - y]) EllipticK[y] *)
```

If the `x`a are changed to `y`s, or vice versa, the output will be `π/2`.

Comment: Thank you! Suggested method indeed works.